# Copy calendars items without prefixing subject line with "Copy: "?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar, xcopy

I'm trying to drag all items from a calendar in one PST file to a calendar in another.  I am prompted to Choose between "Copy", "Copy Series", "Copy Occurrences".  No matter what I choose, the subject line of the items get prepended with prefix "Copy: ".  In calendar view, this uses up all the available space for displaying the subject line, thus rendering the calendar view useless.  I have no option to *move* the items instead.

I tried switching to Folder View in the navigation pane of Outlook, then copying the entire calendar from source PST file to destination PST file.  *Then* I tried copying the items from the copied calendar to the Primary calendar.  Same thing.

It seems that what I want to do is very simple.  Is there any way toa avoid this perplexing, unwanted modification of the subject line that renders the calendar view useless?  I am using Outlook 2013 on Windows 7, in a corporate environment.

Comment: How do you copy the calendar entries? When tested here, I press Ctrl to select multiple meetings and then right click to choose Copy. Go to new calendar folder and press Ctrl+V to paste. I haven't seen "Copy" in the meeting name.

Comment: What I do (ideally at start of year) is export all mail & calendar items from Exchange server account to a snapshot.pst file, copy to a 2019.pst, then prune away messages outside of 2019, and meetings that have no presence in 2019 (including recurrence). I accidentally erased all meetings, so I displayed all meetings from snapshot.pst in List view, selected all, then tried Ctrl-drag and simple drag (without Ctrl).  That's when a popup menu gives me the various copy options in my original post. No move options.

Comment: Instead of copying and pasting, you can export calendar items to a new PST file and then import it to the new calendar folder.

Comment: That works like a charm. Can you please post that as the answer?  It does make me wonder what they had in mind in prepending all drag-copied items with "Copy: ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of copying and pasting, you can export calendar items to a new PST file and then import it to the new calendar folder.